# Using R, how do we split a dataframe to create a dynamic multi-tabbed excel file for each customer in the dataframe with a tab for each product

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Given this dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

df.1 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 , ~prod,
  'cust1',  '202201', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202202', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202203', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust1',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202203', 5, 10,'online',
  'cust2',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202202', 5, 10,'online',
  'cust3',  '202204', 5, 10,'online'
 'cust4',  '202101', NA, NA, 'online',
  'cust4',  '202102', NA,10, 'online'
  
)
```

I am trying to create an excel file for each customer and dynamically add tabs based on the variable `prod`, where some files may have 1 tab and others more than 1 based upon how many products they have.

I would also like to remove any column where all values are `NA` so in this simple example, the file for **cust4** would not have a column `cost1`.

Here is what I tried.  It seems to split the file by customer and product, but it doesn't- create a file for each customer and it doesn't remove the column where all values are NA

```
list(tab1 = df.1) %>%
  map(\(df) split(df, list(df.1$customer, df.1$prod), drop =T)) %>%
  janitor::remove_empty(., which = 'cols') %>% 
  iwalk(\(df, nm) write.xlsx(df, paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6))
```

How can I accomplish this?  I would expect 4 files with a tab for each product they actually have, and in cust4's case only 4 columns instead of 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach to achieve your desired result, which

1. splits the dataset by `customer`
2. uses `iwalk` to loop over the list of customer dataframes
3. removes empty columns
4. splits the customer df by `prod`
5. exports the resulting list of product dataframes

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

df.1 %>% 
  split(.$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    df %>%
      janitor::remove_empty(which = 'cols') %>% 
      split(.$prod) |> 
      write.xlsx(paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6)
  })

read.xlsx("cust4.xlsx", "online")
#>   customer period cost2   prod
#> 1    cust4 202101    NA online
#> 2    cust4 202102    10 online
```

And thanks to the comment by @MrFlick we could achieve the same result using the base pipe `|>` like so:

```
df.1 |>  
  split(~customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    df |> 
      janitor::remove_empty(which = 'cols') |> 
      split(~prod) |> 
      write.xlsx(paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6)
  })
```

**EDIT** You could remove empty cols per product by first splitting by `prod` and by using `map` to get rid of the empty cols like so:

```
df.1 |>  
  split(~customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    df |> 
      split(~prod) |> 
      map(~janitor::remove_empty(.x, which = 'cols')) |>
      write.xlsx(paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for my use case

Comment: Might be better to use the new formula syntax for split: `split(~customer)` then it would work with `|>` or `%>%`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Much appreciated. Wasn't aware of the formula syntax. For me, not being able to use split in a pipeline was one of the most annoying things about the base pipe. :D

Comment: I just realized, I actually need to remove the empty cols after it is split by prod when I reorder the remove_empty and split functions above I get an error that says unique() applies only to vectors.  Any thoughts on how to perform the split first and then remove the empty cols?

Comment: Not a big deal. In that case we have to swap the split and remove steps. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work in my real data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (tested) solution.
To have the customers as file names, you must `iwalk` after splitting by customer only. Then split by `prod` to have the respective tabs but what is saved is this list, the result of the 2nd split all saved in one instruction.

```
split(df.1, df.1$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(y, nm) {
    split(y, y$prod) %>% write.xlsx(paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), startRow = 6)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks.  This mostly accomplished what I was trying to do except remove the column of NA for cust4